# I want to use teams outgoing webhook to send comments on a post to salesforce. Is there a way to send comments from teams to salesforce

Tags: salesforce, integration, microsoft-teams

My scenario is, if someone posts a discussion in salesforce community, we are sending it to teams through incoming webhook. I would like to explore if we can reply in the post, can we send it back to salesforce

I tried teams integration for salesforce but it doesn't work for salesforce communities.

Comment: If you want to configure outgoing webhook, we need to provide an API endpoint. Do you have any API endpoint at Salesforce side so that you can post back the reply to that specific post in Salesforce community. Please do check this sample for reference - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/outgoing-webhook

Comment: Hi I created salesforce site and provided that as an endpoint. And tried creating a handler class to handle the payload but i didn't see any data.

Comment: Engineering team has said that Outgoing webhook doesn’t seem suitable for this scenario. O365 Connectors or PowerAutomate seem to cover this. Can you please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/salesforce/ and check which could best suit the needs.